# Javascript Hamburger menu firing but invisible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation

I created a responsive Hamburger menu using javascript, which seems to be firing properly, the only problem is that the drop down menu and anchors are completely invisible when I "open" the menu despite being present in the Chrome Inspector (ie when i select a list item/anchor element in the inspector, an area where I should see the item is highlighted, but there's nothing there!)

I thought it could be the image/text in the next container concealing the elements, but I made a fresh .html with only the nav elements present and when I viewed that in the browser, same problem.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 660px) {
    
    .icon {
        display: inline-block;
        color: black;
        position: absolute;
        right: 2rem;
        
    }
    
        nav {
        position: relative;
        height: 4rem;
    }
    
    .nav-links {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 4rem;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #63B4C9;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0.5rem;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .nav-links li a {
        display: block;
        padding: 0.5rem;
        text-align: center;
    }

}
```

```html
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arapey|Homemade+Apple|Fira+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Starter Files</title>
</head>
<body>
  <nav id="theNav" class="nav">
    <img src="images/logo.svg" class="logo">
     <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li><a href="#">Classes</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Planting Info</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>     
  </nav>


      <script>

  $(".icon").click(function(){
    $(".nav-links").slideToggle();    
  });

  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you put your on codepen.io so I can better help you?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] making sure it still displays the problem. What you posted (while clearly misses some styles) seems to [work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/k8hs0bpm/) - when the example is sized below 660px.